# redmine: How can I sort by custom field in module

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I`ve got

```
issue.descendants.visible.sort_by(&:lft)
```

which gets descendant issues sorted my **:lft**

How can I sort by custom field with was created via CustomField module?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort issues by custom field values via tables join

```rb
issues = Issue.all.joins("left outer join #{CustomValue.table_name} on #{CustomValue.table_name}.customized_type='#{Issue.name}' and #{CustomValue.table_name}.customized_id=#{Issue.table_name}.id")
issues = issues.order "#{CustomValue.table_name}.value"
```

Just add nessecary conditions in join expression (in this example takes all custom issue values)

Comment: Ok. I will try and notice you